# Cheeger-Gromoll Splitting in Peterson's text

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[image]

So I don't see how the distance function allows us to conclude that $M=U_0\times \mathbb{R}$. Could someone explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the level sets of $r$, i.e. at the sets $\{x: r(x)=c\} =: U_c$ The condition on the Hessian allows to conclude that the curves normal to these level sets are complete geodesics and that the level sets have no focal points. The diffeomorphism $U_0\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$ can be written down explicitly by looking at the exponential map restricted to the normal bundle of any of the hypersurfaces $U_c$, e.g. of $U_0$.

Comment: Is the isometric map the following. $\exp(t(\nabla r)(p))$.

Comment: @Enigma yes, if $p\in U_0$ and $\nabla r$ is evaluated at $p$. The latter is of course just one of two choices of unit normal to $U_0$ in $p$. It's a diffeomorphism and an isometry along the normal geodesics and when restricted to $U_0$, but not a global isometry

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean it is not a global isometry? From what I read in Petersen and in Eschenburg-Heintze this map should be an isometry. I was trying to prove that, but I have difficulty calculating it's derivative. Can you give some details?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulios the map Enigma writes down is an isometry from it's domain to it's target. This is shown by calculating the effect of that map on the metric. This is a local argument, so it does not show the map is a global isometry (i.e. that the geodesics have maximal length and $U_0$ can be chosen so that the image covers all of $M$). For that another reason has to be given. It's been quite a while and I'm no longer working in this area, so I have to ask you to find some other source for the calculations. Most books on Differential Geometry should cover the necessary foundations.